# Programming microcontroller via UART

Tags: microcontroller, programming

Can I program or flash a microcontroller using UART? I previously thought UART is only for communication purposes.

Comment: If there's something in the microcontroller that is able to turn *communication* into flash operations, then yes.  Otherwise, no.  The same goes for most any other *communication* interface.  Most typically for a UART, that would be a "bootloader" either in factory ROM or already put in flash by some other method.

Comment: @Arkojit Please be more specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few micro's have a uart bootloader rom from the factory.
mid range STM8's for example.

Others can have a bootloader programmed into flash. Arduinos come with Optiboot put into the flash by the pcb assembler (not Atmel).

To have a bootloader requires in-system self-programmability. It helps if it can execute code from ram, but this is not needed (PIC). Some micros (e.g AVR) have code protect arrangements specifically to protect a bootloader area of flash.

It might be useful for people to note micros that have a factory bootloader in the comments below as it is a useful feature manufacturers sometimes hide on page 570

Answer (score 1):

Many microcontrollers can be programmed over UART, provided that the microcontroller in question has a suitable bootloader. Google "uart bootloader" and you'll see many examples.

Comment: I would say *any* microcontroller with UART and a bootloader supporting UART firmware uploading can be...

Comment: The microcontroller also needs to support in-system flash programming of the executable code memory, which is tricky if the bootloader has to run from the same memory space. Often there's a way to partition the memory or erase one page while the bootloader is running in the other page.

Comment: @MarkU Depends on what is required. It can get loaded into RAM after each boot from host/external flash.